# Rdkafka auto commit the offset after processing the message?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

When `enable.auto.commit` is set to `true`, does Rdkafka ensure that it only commets the offset which has been processed by application?

Suppose there is a message at offset 204301.
Is that possible that offset 204301 has been committed before the applicate completes the processing on this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will commit any offset which has been polled from library - librdkafka has no way to know if you are done processing your message

You will have to commit manually if you want to preserve at least once semantic 100% time in case of failure.

Best thing to do is to poll some data, treat them (either one by one or by batch), and once this is done, commit offset, every X messages or Y ms (don't commit every messages, this would keep broker busy for no reason)

Comment: When the offsets_store() API PR has been merged it will allow you to use auto commits but control exactly what offsets to store for commit. PR here https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/pull/339